# why delay() function not delaying the .load() function?

Tags: jquery

$("#hastable").delay(2000).load("tbl_clients.php?page=");
It is not working for me.

But otherwise all effect delay successfully for this .delay() function like .hide(),.show()

Comment: I can confirm this, .delay() does not delay the load() function. ( jQuery 1.4.3. )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's not working for you, but here's an alternative to jQuery's delay function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $("#hastable").load("tbl_clients.php?page=");
}, 2000);
```